# security tools for mysql

Tags: mysql, security

We are using MySQL Community version on Windows and are trying to secure it as best we can.  Assuming that changing the version (for example purchasing the Enterprise edition) is not possible in our environment, I would love to hear how others are doing things such as:

- Auditing
- Alerts
- Monitoring
- Password rules
- Account disabling after inactive for X days
- Backups
- Integrity checking
- Encryption
- Steganography detection

For example, we are using the general log for our cheap "auditing".  Maybe not the best solution, but something is better than nothing.  Any free tools out there, or maybe homegrown scripts anyone would like to suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few starting points (and I don't have answers to everything).
Disclosure: I suggest a couple tools that were written by myself (and of course used in production).

- Consider this [login audit plugin](http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/introducing-audit_login-simple-mysql-login-logfile-based-auditing) (open sourced, [find in GitHub](https://github.com/outbrain/audit_login)). I developed & compiled in on Linux, you will have to find your way on Windows. This plugin will log any login attempt (successful or failed) onto your server.

We use the above to audit any login on any of our servers -- using logstash to aggregate all our logs, and kibana to view/query it. Likewise, you can query this log and send alerts to graphite / query by Nagios -- I don not know what bests suits Windows.

- Consider common_schema's [security_audit](http://common-schema.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/common_schema/doc/html/security_audit.html). This will generate a report on bad security settings (duplicate passwords, excessive privileges etc.). It does not do any steganography.
- Check out [GreenSQL](http://www.greensql.com/) - I never tried it myself. It's a proxy sittting between your clients and your MySQL server, that can analyse and block queries on the fly.
- Check out MariaDB security enhancements, e.g. [role management](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/create-role-statement/). Available [for Windows](https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/5.5.35/).

Answer (score 0):

I have replied here [MySQL query log](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54546/mysql-query-log/54689#54689)

There are other methods for logging and secure your server using audit plugins and binary log, Using MySQL proxy etc..

Comment: Mahesh, thanks for the info!  I will look into some of the other available MySQL logs.  The plugins don't apply to me because we're stuck on Windows, and on the Community version, not Enterprise.