# How to Identify the user who issued MySQL Shutdown command

Tags: mysql, audit, log, shutdown

We have had several situations when our production MySQL server suddenly became unavailable.  The error log just shows "Normal shutdown" followed by the typical shutdown messages.  How can I determine the Linux or MySQL user account and host name of the connection issuing the shutdown command?

Answer (score 1):

Check the secure log in the event it was run via a sudo service call

```
sudo grep mysql /var/log/secure
```

Check to see if there's any mysql related stuff going on in cronjobs

```
sudo grep mysql /var/log/cron
```

Check shell histories for mysqladmin calls

cd /home; for u in *: do; sudo grep mysql /home/$u/.bash_history; done

Check with people you know that either have sudo or mysql root access on this machine

```
"Hey, which one of you has been shutting down mysql?"
```

Answer (score 1):

For security concern who executed what queries at what time etc.. you should use "Audit Plugins".
You can refer my existing answer here https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/62477/6037

Ofcourse you can find "mysqladmin" using shell histories or tracing "General/Error log" of MySQL server.

For example if you have General log enabled either in a  "Table" or "File"
you can find out a "command_type" as "shutdown" and you will come to know who executed it.

> SELECT * FROM general_log WHERE command_type='shutdown';

Answer (score 1):

One perfect example why root access even for admins is bad. Maintaining a sudoers file and a centralized database of privileged users and groups(LDAP for example) would help solving problems like this.

One note: the wrongdoer might well be a cronjob. I'd check that.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see who issued shutdown from a Linux viewpoint and if you are real risk taker, ***I have a very dangerous but fun suggestion***.

You could create a special log file that records when `service mysql stop` is issued or if mysqld_safe decides to shutdown.

Let's say you want the file to be called `/var/lib/mysql/.shutdown_signals`

Run the following two lines

```
echo -n > /var/lib/mysql/.shutdown_signals
chown mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql/.shutdown_signals
cp /etc/init.d/mysql /etc/init.d/mysql_new
vi /etc/init.d/mysql_new
```

Look for these lines or something to this effect

```
'stop')
  # Stop daemon. We use a signal here to avoid having to know the
  # root password.
```

or

```
'restart')
  # Stop the service and regardless of whether it was
  # running or not, start it again.
```

Simply add these lines

```
DT=`date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`
echo "Shutdown Issued : ${DT}"
whoami >> .shutdown_signals
w      >> .shutdown_signals
```

Now, find mysqld_safe

```
which mysqld_safe
```

It will echo

```
/usr/bin/mysqld_safe
```

Next, run these

```
cp /usr/bin/mysqld_safe /usr/bin/mysqld_safe_new
vi /usr/bin/mysqld_safe_new
```

Look for the word `shutdown`. You should find something like this

```
while true
do
  rm -f $safe_mysql_unix_port "$pid_file"       # Some extra safety

  eval_log_error "$cmd"

  if test ! -f "$pid_file"              # This is removed if normal shutdown
  then
    break
  fi
```

Change the `if ... then` to

```
  if test ! -f "$pid_file"              # This is removed if normal shutdown
  then
    DT=`date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`
    echo "Shutdown Issued : ${DT}"
    whoami >> .shutdown_signals
    w      >> .shutdown_signals
    break
  fi
```

You will need to shutdown mysql and switch the files around

```
service mysql stop
mv /usr/bin/mysqld_safe /usr/bin/mysqld_safe_old
mv /usr/bin/mysqld_safe_new /usr/bin/mysqld_safe
mv /etc/init.d/mysql /etc/init.d/mysql_old
mv /etc/init.d/mysql_new /etc/init.d/mysql
service mysql start
```

Going forward, you simply run

```
tail -30 /var/lib/mysql/.shutdown_signals
```

So, if you are truly a risk taker...

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

**WARNING !!!** Administer databases responsibly. Do risky things in Staging or Dev VMs first. If you are 100% successful, then

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!